# How to change GridView.ItemTemplate while app is running?

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In my app I have page with GridView and ComboBox. I want to change GridView.ItemTemplate property according to selected item in ComboBox. How should I implement it?

btw, I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657618/metro-app-change-gridview-itemtemplate-programatically), but it is quite old and it does not look like "best practice". (How visibility/invisibility of ui control affects cpu/gpu load?)

My GridView:

```
<GridView x:Name="gridViewMain" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource gridViewMainItemTemplate}"
              Loaded="gridViewMain_Loaded" LayoutUpdated="gridViewMain_LayoutUpdated">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
                <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="GridViewClick"
                                       TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </GridView>
```

One of my templates:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="gridViewMainItemTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="gridATemplate" Width="185" Height="288">
            <Image x:Name="imgATemplate" Source="{Binding image_url}" Stretch="UniformToFill"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockTitle" Text="{Binding title}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"
                           MaxHeight="50" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockType" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding type}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockProgressL" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"
                               Text="Progress:" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockProgressV" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"
                               Text="{Binding watched_episodes}" Margin="10,0,0,10" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: +1 to bring it back to 0 simply because it's not helpful when people downvote something without explanation.

Comment: Have you considered adding an event to the combobox? `this.ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);` . The function `ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` will execute whenever the combobox is changed. Inside of that function you can then change the GridView.

Comment: I should have actually read this before leaving the page, you're likely looking at [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector) as the best route here. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do this! In XAML you can do anything. What you cannot do is change the Template on the fly without re-rendering. Remember, this is like telling your printer to use card stock. It will obey. If you change the setting to use notebook paper, it will obey that, too. You will just have to print again since it has already printed on card stock.

There are a few ways for you to re-render a GridView. One way is to navigate away from the page and navigate back. That's not ideal sounding in your scenario. Odds are, in your scenario, you just need to reset the ObservableCollection you are using. Like this:

```
void Reset<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
{
    var original = collection.ToArray();
    collection.Clear();
    foreach (var item in original)
        collection.Add(item);
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Could you please explain me how to set and change GridView's ItemTemplate xaml property? I added XAML markup to question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use datatemplateselector

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bryanbolling/archive/2012/12/08/how-to-control-the-datatemplateselector-in-windows-store-apps.aspx

You can create multiple itemtemplates and choose which one to display based on any condition.

You'll have to refresh the gridview whenever the selection changes.

Comment: I'm sorry but this will not work. When the user changes the `combobox` the `gridview` will not change until it re-renders the content. A selector is probably part of his solution, but it doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT, that's why I said they'll have to refresh the gridview whenever the selection changes.  They can do this in many ways, the easiest would be to set the source to null, then back to the collection and it will rebind everything.  Just changing the property won't do that.

Comment: We agree. Sorry if there was confusion.